# Restful web service invocation in BPEL

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl, bpel

### My question is that:

Is there any method that I can use restful web services such as Google Map or Youtube in BPEL. I know that BPEL works with SOAP web services that have WSDL file. But, I asked to do a project which should contain restful web services work with BPEL. I appreciate any hints,links and tutorials on the inetrnet.

Note:

- I am very new to both web service and bpel concepts. I just implemented some samples from internet.
- I use eclipse helios, Apache Tomcat 7.0, Apache ODE server, BPEL designer

Answer (score 4):

Apache ODE supports a custom HTTP binding that allows the orchestration of RESTful HTTP services. See [1] for details. The `TestHTTPBinding`* test cases [2] may help as a starter.

[1] http://ode.apache.org/wsdl-11-extensions-for-rest.html
[2] http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ode/trunk/axis2-war/src/test/resources/

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample REST service invocation process here as well.
[TestRESTProcess in WSO2 BPS sample process repository](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/products/bps/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/bpel/2.0/TestRESTProcess/)

Comment: Denis... your link is broken. Can you provide an updated one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple SOAP web service that calls the RESTful web service for you.