# What is the current state of support for invoking RESTful services from BPEL workflow engines like ODE, Riftsaw, and Intalio BPMS?

Tags: rest, workflow, bpel, bpmn, apache-ode

We have several web services that are SOAP-based but we've been slowly converting them to a RESTful style. New services will be RESTful only.

I need to integrate a BPEL workflow engine into our system that supports both.

What is the current state of support for invoking RESTful services from BPEL workflow engines like ODE, Riftsaw, or Intalio BPMS?

Comment: Do you think you can find the needed information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194482/restful-web-service-invocation-in-bpel ?

Answer (score 0):

Intalio|BPMS supports REST binding for REST services. Intalio|BPMS Designer goes as far as providing you with a nice editor to create the WSDL and map the REST service, so the WSDL generation is a non-issue.