# Creating WSO2 BPEL project for JSON webservices

Tags: json, eclipse, web-services, wso2, bpel

I have the WSO2 Developer Studio Eclipse Plugin downloaded. And I was looking at this tutorial: http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/07/eclipse-bpel-designer-wso2bps-tutorial/. But it seems to be talking about using SOAP. But my webservices, which are written in PHP(in live servers) are REST using JSON. Accepts data via HTTP GET methods by these webservices and respond back with JSON data.

So how will I implement a BPEL project making use of the JSON webservices? Any ideas or suggestion? Am completely new to this. Thank you.

**EDIT**

When I created the BPEL Process, I have used `HTTP` from the dropdown instead of `SOAP`

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 uses a custom variant of [the Apache ODE engine](http://ode.apache.org/) for executing BPEL processes. ODE [provides extensions for REST](http://ode.apache.org/extensions/wsdl-11-extensions-for-rest.html), which you can try out. However, I am not sure if these extensions also support JSON or if they just allow XML data. Also [have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258197/1127892).